# Strategy pattern to consume REST API

Tags: api, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have to consume two different REST API providers about VoIP. Both API do the same with different endpoints and parameters. I'm modeling classes as strategy pattern and the problem that i have encountered is the parameters of each method strategy because are different.

```
public interface VoIPRequests
{
    string ApiKey { get; set; }

    string GetExtensionsList();
    string TriggerCall();
    string DropCall();
    string RedirectCall();
}
```

How can i change parameters for each of this methods depend on the implementation?.
It's good idea use strategy pattern for this case?
There is another pattern that suits better?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what differs, and what stays the same?

Comment: check if there are some common denominators in the parameters, and what instead is fixed per-implementation. Fixed data should be injected into the actual implementation.
Also, as @MarkSeemann pointed out, can you give more details?

Comment: TriggerCall(), one api only needs one parameter "To" , and other api has two mandatory parameters "extension" and "destination", in addition two optional more parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment thread:

> TriggerCall(), one api only needs one parameter "To" , and other api has two mandatory parameters "extension" and "destination"

I'll focus on `TriggerCall`, then, and let you extrapolate from there.

## Implementation 1

```
public class VoIPRequests1 : VoIPRequests
{
    private readonly object to; // Give this a more appropriate type

    public VoIPRequests1(object to)
    {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public string TriggerCall()
    {
        // Use this.to here and return string;
    }

    // Other interface members go here...
}
```

## Implementation 2

```
public class VoIPRequests2 : VoIPRequests
{
    private readonly object extension; // Give this a more appropriate type
    private readonly object destination; // Give this a more appropriate type

    public VoIPRequests2(object extension, object destination)
    {
        this.extension = extension;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public string TriggerCall()
    {
        // Use this.extension and this.destination here and return string;
    }

    // Other interface members go here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this method the client must know details of specific implementation or no?

Comment: @fito Why is that?

Comment: The idea is VoIP voip = VoIPFactory.GetFactoryType(); GetFactoryType() returns specific implementation then use voip.TriggerCall() so that object client doesnt know implementation details. I don't know if I have explained myself

Comment: @fito Not really, no... You're probably wondering where `to`, `extension`, and `destination` will come from... is that it?

Comment: Yes, these parameters must be transparent for the caller of specific implementations methods.

Comment: @fito Indeed, that's why you feed them via the constructor: so that the caller doesn't have to supply them when calling the method.